# Push docker container from locak to aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

When I attempt to push my tagged docker repo to ecr I receive error:

```
 ->  ~  docker push 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:latest                                                                                                                                                                                           1 ↵  1834  00:14:14
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com]
a41ec2e4dc40: Preparing
62b872ff53d4: Preparing
a628002c2154: Preparing
9f15c5e37d02: Preparing
efdebd147565: Preparing
32411a9a984e: Waiting
1bd26e8168dc: Waiting
ffc9b21953f4: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

User has all permissions to push image ? :

[image]

I have followed steps to tag image:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

docker tag cda-flask-app:latest 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

docker push 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I've configured the CLI using `aws configure` as per doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration . I don't believe I'm missing any steps, yet when I try to push the image i receive permissions issue. Is there an iextra step I need to complete in order to push the image from local to ecr ?

Update:

Using :

```
docker tag cda-flask-app:latest 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com       

docker push 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cda-flask-app:latest
```

returns error:

```
The push refers to repository [169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cda-flask-app]
a41ec2e4dc40: Preparing
62b872ff53d4: Preparing
a628002c2154: Preparing
9f15c5e37d02: Preparing
efdebd147565: Preparing
32411a9a984e: Waiting
1bd26e8168dc: Waiting
ffc9b21953f4: Waiting
name unknown: The repository with name 'cda-flask-app' does not exist in the registry with id '169729465422'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the image name. If should be in the form of `repository/image:tag`.

In your case it should be `169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myimage:latest`.

Without the `/`, docker try to push to the default registry `docker.io` the image `169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` with `latest` tag.

And before pushing an image to ECR, you need to create the "repository" into the ECR console with the "Create repository button":
[image: ECR Console]

Comment: thanks, please see question update, have I followed your instructions correctly ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to create the "repository" first in ACR. The term "repository" is a bit misleading as as ECR should already be a repository but I don't really know how I would name it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late, however:

Your ECR repository should be named like your image, so if you push

```
docker push 169729465422.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cda-flask-app:latest
```

then your repository in ECR should be named *cda-flask-app* too. That is why docker is not finding the right repository.

Comment: Thank you. The local image name should match to AWS ECR repo URI.